# "BE to VERB" construction in "you are to blame"

Tags: idioms, infinitive-clauses

> 1. The plane is to take off at 9pm
> 2. You are to blame

1 refer to what will happen in the future as the "be + to +verb" construction is normally used for. In 2, "you" is like the object of "blame". Could you explain this usage to me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idiom *BE to VERB* has three distinct meanings:

1. ***active sense*** = ‘Be appointed, expected, supposed, obliged *to VERB* at some point in the future’

   > I am to go to London tomorrow. ... *I am supposed to go to London tomorrow*.
   >
   > I was to see the Minister yesterday, but he was called away. ... *I had an appointment to see the Minister, but ...*.
   >
   > The plane is to take off at 9pm. ... *The plane is expected to take off at 9pm.*
2. ***passive sense*** = ‘Be worthy of being or ‘expected to be VERBed’. This 'passival' infinitive also appears without *BE* as a postposited modifier. The phrase may also be  expressed with an explicit passive, *BE to **be** VERBed*, or with *for VERBing*.

   > This room is to let. ... *This room is to be let (=rented)*.
   >
   > These doughnuts are to share. ... *These doughnuts are for sharing*.
   >   I got us doughnuts to share. ... *I got doughnuts for us to share*.
   >
   > You are to blame. ... *You deserve to be blamed*.

   Compare *HAVE to VERB*, where *to VERB* has the same passive sense: ‘We have several treatments to show you’.
3. ***conditional sense*** = ‘If [subject] VERBed’. The past form *were*, without inflection for 3rd person singular, may express a tentative or hypothetical condition; this may be introduced with *if*, or *were* may invert with the subject.

   > If he were to win the lottery he might retire. *OR*
   >   Were he to win the lottery he might retire. ... *If he won the lottery he might retire*.

Comment: Thanks .Most grammar references I found only said about the 1st usage.

Comment: I think Sense 2 might be more common than you think.  *The donuts are to share, the cookies are to eat, the cake is to sell, the muffins are to keep*.  These seem to me like perfectly common phrases, perhaps a little informal.

Comment: In fact, if I rephrase as the more formal *The donuts are to be shared*, it sounds to my ear more  as if I am giving an order.  Sense 2 merely expresses the intended use of the donuts.

Comment: @NateEldredge You're right. I tried to think of examples but drew a blank. I'll fix.