# What is the POS of blame in "be to blame"?

Tags: verbs, idioms, idiomatic-language, nouns, parts-of-speech

> You are to blame.

In [this accepted answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/75616/you-were-to-blame-vs-you-were-to-be-blamed#:%7E:text=In%20the%20first%20sentence%20%22to%20blame%22%20is%20an%20idiom%2C%20in%20which%20the%20word%20blame%20is%20a%20noun) blame was claimed to be a noun, but in [this accepted one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/32917/10484), it became a verb. I wonder what its part of speech should be? If it is a noun, why?

Comment: As the first answer says, **to blame** is an established phrase which you have to accept as such. It doesn't really matter whether _blame_ is a noun or a verb.

Comment: It is a plain form **verb**. Note that "to" acts as the infinitival marker, not as a preposition.    See James K's answer for more info.

Comment: @KateBunting - don't we sometimes use 'to' to link a subject and an action to signify purpose, suitability, applicability, etc, e.g. that cake is to eat, not [to] look at, a hungry tiger is a creature to avoid, that pretty frock is to die for!

Comment: "To" is a subordinator, a special marker for VPs of infinitival clauses. In the OP's example, the infinitival clause "to blame" is predicative complement of the verb "be".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blame is a verb.  It is the infinitive form of the verb marked with the particle "to".

Evidence that it isn't a noun comes from the fact that it couldn't take a determiner:  *You are to my blame.  *You are to the blame.  Moreover it there are sentence patterns with verbs like "eat" that aren't also used as nouns "You are to eat".

Comment: Given the context, I might (perhaps) worry if someone said 'you are to eat' to me, particularly if I suspected them of being a cannibal.

Comment: Yes,  I suspect grammar might be the least of my worries!

Comment: So, "you are to thank" means "you are the person who should be thanked"? Is "you are to thank" also idiomatic?

Comment: @LernerZhang - idiomatic. _Who's to thank for the Modern American Thanksgiving Menu?_, _Ronaldo is to thank for winning the Carabao Cup_, _You are to thank for a brisk start to the New Year_, _I truly didn't imagine that selling a house would be this quick and I believe you are to thank for that_.